# Different import syntaxes not equivalent?

Tags: python, import, sympy

I tried two different import syntaxes I thought were equivalent. Weirdness seems to ensue:

```
In [7]: import sympy

In [8]:sympy.physics.units.find_unit("Giga Electron Volt")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-8a26ac4a085a>", line 1, in <module>
    sympy.physics.units.find_unit("Giga Electron Volt")

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'physics'


In [9]:import sympy.physics.units as u

In [10]:u.find_unit("coul")
Out[10]: ['coulomb', 'coulombs']

In [11]:import sympy

In [12]:sympy.physics.units.find_unit("coul")
Out[12]: ['coulomb', 'coulombs']
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the difference between a subpackage and an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code of sympy here: [https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/**init**.py#L55](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/__init__.py#L55)

```
from .calculus import *
# Adds about .04-.05 seconds of import time
# from combinatorics import *
# This module is slow to import:
#from physics import units
from .plotting import plot, textplot, plot_backends, plot_implicit
```

They are not importing the physics module, because it takes obviously quite some time to load. This is why you get the error in the first try.

After loading it manually, the interpreter has it loaded and knows where it is (from your manual import). Thats why it works on the second try.

So the phenomenon is not regarded to python import functionality, but to the module initialization.

P.S.
If you uncomment the line that loads `unit` from the physics module, it would be

```
import sympy
sympy.units.find_unit("coul")
```